# getSherlockActivity().startActionMode return a null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, contextual-action-bar

I'm trying to start the action mode on a 4.2 device but the result is a null. I'm not sure its an sherlock issue because the native call is the one failing.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id{
   CustomCell cell = (CustomCell) view.getTag();
   if (cell == null) {
        return false;
    }
    mGridView.setChocieMode(LibraryGridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    if (mActionMode != null) {
        return false;
    }
   mActionMode = getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(mActionCallback);
   cell.setSelected(true);
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Turns out that onCreateActionMode in ActionMode.Callback returned false, set the return value to true solved the issue